# AFNetworking read text/html as html and not JSON

Tags: afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking and making a request to my server. Ideally my server returns JSON (with the correct content-type=application/json header) But sometimes something bad happens and POST request just returns raw html. When this happens I just want to read the html as a string. The problem is that it I can't get AFNetworking to deal with anything that isn't json or xml. I already added text/html to set of acceptedContentTypes.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:KIWI_URL parameters:postParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id objects) {
        NSLog(objects);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"10error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing responseSerializer. After manager initialization add this code:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

In success block you can read the response using:

```
NSLog(@"RESPONSE:\n%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:1]);
```

Comment: My next question: is there a way for it to default to whichever the content type is? I know that is what AFNetworking is designed to do. But why didn't they add support for text/html?

Comment: I don't know why they didn't add support for text/html. There is lots of ready response serialzer, f.ex. AFJSONResponseSerializer, AFXMLParserResponseSerializer, AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer, AFPropertyListResponseSerializer, AFImageResponseSerializer. If there isn't response serializer you need, you can create new class which inherit from AFHTTPResponseSerializer and specify there your own response serializer. You can look at AFURLResponseSerialization.m where are defined serializers and create new similar to those ones.